# Cant get a timer to work correctly c++

Tags: c++, timer

I am trying to get a timer to count two times but I have been having trouble with it it will perform its task once but not again, I have no idea where I am going wrong and I can find anything on the internet that helps as I am running my code in a game loop that runs at 1000FPS.

This is the header code.

```
clock_t endBoost = clock() + 3.0f * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
clock_t slow = clock() + 5.0f * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

This is the main code.

```
bool overheat = false;
if(overheat == false)
{
    if(myEngine->KeyHeld(Key_Space))
    {
        timer = clock();
        if(timer < endBoost)
        {
            stringstream outBoost;
            outBoost << "!BOOST!";
            myFont->Draw(outBoost.str(), 300, 200);
            outBoost.str("");
            carSpeedIncrement = 0.1f;
        }

    }
}

if(timer > endBoost)
{
    overheat = true;
}
if(timer < slow && overheat == true)
{
    overheat = false;
    carSpeedIncrement = 0.1f;
}
```

Any Help is Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're initializing `endBoost` and `slow` and never changing their values.  But these are initialized based on the `clock()` value and never changed.  The current value of `timer` will very quickly be greater than both `endBoost` and `slow` and will forever remain so.

Comment: Yes please if you could give me an idea on how to fix it that would be good.

Comment: @MooingDuck Why are you editing my answer???  I don't think `sleep` has anything to do with the original question.

Comment: Because your answer was good, but missing an example timer to look into.  I remedied that for you.  `sleep` is the simplest timer to use in non-framework code, and is the heart of all other timers.

Comment: Bad form, @MooingDuck.  Provide your own answer if you want, but don't go around putting words into other's answers without their permission.

Comment: @bobthemac I'm not familiar with the keypress-handling, but perhaps you can reset `endBoost` to ("now" + 3 seconds) as soon as the user starts pressing the key?

Comment: @abelenky Site says it is ok to modify other people's answers to make them better. But it is bad form to make them worse. There is nothing about "getting permission to alter other people's answers" mentioned. If the original poster, or anyone else, doesn't like the changes, they can always edit it again.

Answer (score -1):

*"I am trying to get a counter to count two times"*

I don't see anything that resembles a counter in this code.
You must be much clearer about what your meaning.

Comment: I am using the clock function in the time.h file as my counter. it works for the right amount of time the first time I use it but them it doesn't work again

Comment: @bobthemac: clock is a clock.  clock is not a timer.

Comment: @MooingDuck but a clock can be used as a timer this is how examples show it to be done on the internet.

Comment: @bobthemac: Don't use a clock as a timer, that's a bad idea.  It can be done, but it will use 100% of your processor while it waits, and kill laptop batteries.  Use a timer.